# Python 3.4, error when creating a DataFrame with panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to create a DataFrame with the following:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys

# The inital set of baby names and birth rates
names =['Bob','Jessica','Mary','John','Mel']
births = [968, 155, 77, 578, 973]

#Now we wil zip them together
BabyDataSet = zip(names,births)
    ##we have to add the 'list' for version 3.x
print (list(BabyDataSet))

#create the DataFrame
df = DataFrame(BabyDataSet, columns = ['Names', 'Births'] )
print (df)
```

when I run the program I get the following error: 'data type can't be an iterator'
I read the following, '[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)', but I do not understand how that applies to what I'm doing. Any help and further understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3, `zip` returns an iterator, not a list like it does in python 2.   Just convert it to a list as you construct the DataFrame, like this.

```
df = DataFrame(list(BabyDataSet), columns = ['Names', 'Births'] )
```

Comment: I thought that might fix it but it just gave me another error, 'Shape of passed values is (0,0), indices imply (2,0)

So I thought I was doing it wrong. Could this indicate a problem with my pandas file itself?

Comment: I believe the issue is that BabyDataSet is created as an generator, so the `print(list(BabyDataSet))` line is "eating" it up. Remember that generators can only be iterated through once. Simply removing that line should fix it. What you should probably do is save it as a list when you initialize it so you don't accidentally use up the generator: `BabyDataSet = list(zip(names,births))`

Comment: @ rfan
That fixed the second error and I was able to create my df, thanks to both of you. :)
p.s how do I upvote a helpful comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the dataframe using an alternate syntax that avoids the zip/generator issue entirely.

```
df = DataFrame({'Names': names, 'Births': births})
```

Read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) on initializing dataframes. Pandas simply takes the dictionary, creates one column for each entry with the key as the name and the value as the value.

> Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, or list-like objects

Comment: Could you explain the logic or a provide a link as to how that works?

Comment: Edited, though not sure how helpful that is. I find it pretty intuitive, the dataframe will be initialized with column names as the keys in the dictionary and any iterable or constant as the values of the column.